# setColorFilter to Button without changing stroke

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button

I have an xml with button having a background drawable as :

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black"/>
 </shape>
```

I want to change only the color of the buttons background programmatically.
So i tried this,

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

However, i cannot see the stroke at all when I setColorFIlter().
any inputs?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
GradientDrawable buttonBackground = (GradientDrawable)button.getBackground();
buttonBackground.setColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best solution for your question but its work for sure

```
RippleDrawable rippleImgStart;  
Drawable imgStart;
 final int ColorWhiteOpacity = Color.argb(75,255,255,255); 
 imgStart = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.start); 
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            rippleImgStart = new
                    RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(ColorWhiteOpacity), imgStart, null);
            btn.setImageDrawable(rippleImgStart);
}
```

this is basically use for provide ripple effect on image so u can achieve ripple effect also..

and ColorWhiteOpacity you can use your color and set it to the image.

here you can find example: [link](http://trickyandroid.com/simple-ripple-reveal-elevation-tutorial/)